# Laravel like in where don't return result if space exist before character

Tags: sql, laravel

I don't know how to explain more my question; on laravel I need to return members has code start with `(J or j)` but when I use `('members.code', 'like', 'j%')`;

there are some members in var_dump of code are like `"    J3X", "  jh4", " j5T"`. my code is returning only those who are like `"jH6"; "J9u"` ... but not if they have space or more than one sapce in my result.

I want to return all members that they have code start with j even there is space or more than one space in code.

my query is

```
$query = member::where('members.inscription', '>=', $date_start->startOfDay())
                ->where('members.inscription', '<=', $date_end->endOfDay())
                ->where('members.id_member', '>', 1099)
                ->where('members.code', 'like', 'J%')
                ->orderBy('members.id_member', 'DESC');

$members = $query->get();

var_dump($members); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try trimming whitespace on the left of the member codes before doing a `LIKE` comparison:

```
$query = member::where('members.inscription', '>=', $date_start->startOfDay())
    ->where('members.inscription', '<=', $date_end->endOfDay())
    ->where('members.id_member', '>', 1099)
    ->whereRaw("LTRIM(members.code) LIKE 'J%' OR LTRIM(members.code) LIKE 'j%'")
    ->orderBy('members.id_member', 'DESC');
```

But note that using `LTRIM` this way (or some alternative, such as `REGEXP`) would make the `WHERE` clause non *sargable*, meaning that any index on `members.code` can no longer be used.  If this be a concern to use performance-wise, then consider scrubbing your data to remove this leading whitespace.

Comment: It's still return empty `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#654 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`

Comment: `my code is returning only those who are like "jH6"; "J9u"` ... you said in your original question that you were already not getting an empty result set.  Is my answer giving you an empty result set, and, if so, can you edit your question?

Comment: yes I tried with only one id that has code '     j5x'

Comment: If you want to handle `J` in upper or lower case, then you need additional logic for that.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: `->where('members.id_member', '=', 1024)->whereRaw("LTRIM(members.code_postal) LIKE 'J%' OR LTRIM(members.code_postal) LIKE 'j%'")` it's return so many results I did try `->where('members.id_member', '=', 1024)->whereRaw("LTRIM(members.code_postal) LIKE 'J%'")` and `->where('members.id_member', '=', 1024)->whereRaw("LTRIM(members.code_postal) LIKE 'j%'")`  both return empty result